# save image on folder and store path to database and retrieveit to gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have database that stores the path to an image and I want to display it in a gridview. The path is where a folder is created when a button is clicked; the folder name is the same as the image name. I've successfully created the folder, and the image is also successfully uploaded. The problem is the image won't show on the gridview, there's blank on image coloumn. In my database, the path stored is a full path, with disk letter like "C:\...\folder\image.jpg." What should I do?

button_click:

```
Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName)
Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName)
Dim fileq As String = filename.Replace(filename.ToString, textbox.Text)
Dim folder As String = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~\detail\{0}\", textbox.Text.Trim))

If Not Directory.Exists(folder) Then
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)

If fcover.HasFile Then

   fileupload.SaveAs(folder + fileq + ext)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", folder + fileq + ext)

  End If
End If
```

page_load:

```
cmd.CommandText="select image_path from image"
conn.Open()

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn)
sda.Fill(dt)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: you appear to be simply saving a filename/location to the DB, not the image itself, so the grid is bound to `folder + fileq + ext` which is likely string

Comment: yes, because I want save image on created folder instead of directly to database,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this, here's the code:

```
 Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName)
 Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName)
 Dim fileq As String = filename.Replace(filename.ToString, textbox.Text)
 Dim folder As String = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~\detail\{0}\", textbox.Text.Trim))

    If Not Directory.Exists(folder) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)

    End If
    If fileupload.HasFile Then
        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(String.Format("~\detail\{0}\", textbox.Text.Trim) + fileq + ext))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", String.Format("~\detail\{0}\", textbox.Text.Trim) + fileq + ext)

    End If
```

I just have to use pure string like `string.format("")` instead of `folder` which I use on my code above, the image is successfully uploaded, path is stored and the grid showing the image,